# Are conservative functors stable under pullback?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $A, B$ and $C$ be three small categories and let $f: A\to B$ and $g: C\to B$ two functors such that $g$ is conservative. We can take the pullback as in the following picture:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
P @>{g^{*}}>> A\\
@VVV @VVV\\
C @>{g}>> B.
\end{CD}

My question is: $g^{*}$ is always conservative?
In case the answer is no, for which $f$ is $g^{*}$ conservative?

Furthermore, we can canonically rephrase the above situation in the context of $\infty$-category. So, let $A,B$ and $C$ be three small $\infty$-categories and so on ...

My questions become: the $\infty$-functor $g^{*}$ is always conservative?
In case the answer is no, for which $\infty$-functor $f$ is $g^{*}$ conservative?

Comment: MathJax doesn't know all of LaTeX, so you might want to reconsider your use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the answer is yes because the class of conservative functor is the right class of a factorization system in $Cat_{\infty}$,
see Example 3.1.7 (f) in the article "Left-exact Localizations of $\infty$-Topoi I" (Url: file:///C:/Users/teoxd/Desktop/Left-exact%20Localizations%20of%20infty-topoi%20I-Higher%20Sheaves-%20Anel-Biedermann-Finster-%20Andr%C3%A9%20Joyal.pdf).

Comment: To state it a bit more elementary, conservative $\infty$-functors are exactly those with the right lifting property against the morphism $[1]\to *$, where $[1]$ is the one-arrow category and $*$ is the trivial $\infty$-category. It always holds that pullbacks of maps with a right lifting property still have that right lifting property.